# Determine the number of subgroups of order 7 in $S_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Determine the number of subgroups of order 7 in $S_7$.

```
_____________________________________________________________________________
```

It's like a lottery problem to find the elements of length $7$ being $\binom{7!}{7}$, so there would be that many subgroups since $S_7$ is cyclic

---

Studying for test if its ok ill delete thanks appreciate feedback.

Comment: $S_7$ is not cyclic, but any (sub)group of order $7$ is.

Answer (score 2):

The number of elements of order $7$ is $\frac{7!}{7}$. (think of the cycle decomposition)

each subgroup of order $7$ consists of the identity  and six elements of order $7$.

Distinct subgroups of order $7$ have trivial intersection by Lagrange's theorem.

We conclude the number of subgroups of order $7$ is $\frac{7!}{7\times 6}$